# How to prevent CSS left/right properties from pushing window

Tags: html, css

I am using the right and left properties to place tiny images on the edges of my page.

```
.class img {position:absolute;left:60%}
```

The above example places the image at the end of the screen on the right and only half of the image is visible but it also triggers a horizontal overflow making the page draggable towards the full width of the image.

I tried setting overflow to hidden but it didn't help.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: would be nice if we can see all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you want to allow for items off screen, but prevent scrolling, you're going to have to restrict the user's viewport. This can usually be done by setting the `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` to `hidden` on the `body`.

```css
/* The problem */
.off-screen {
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: red;
}

/* The solution */
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="off-screen"></div>
```

---

*Note*: Depending on your specific situation, this may need to be tweaked, but the concept is the same. I can update this to be more specific if you include more code in your initial post.

Comment: Thanks @Chase Ingebritson. Hiding overflow for `body`. I've been adding it on the image and the image `div`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your images to appear at the right edge of the screen. This should work:

```
.class img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: `... only half of the image is visible but it also triggers a horizontal overflow ...` It sounds like it's supposed to be only half visible.